# What type is a string enum so it can be used as a parameter?

Tags: swift, enums

In my current implementation, I am passing an string enum to a function using `rawValue` like this:

```
enum Compass: String {
  case North, South, East, West
}

func something(key: String) {...}

something(Compass.East.rawValue)
```

Is there a different type other than `String` for the function so I can do something like this?

```
something(Compass.East)
```

I do not want to make the `key` parameter of type `Compass`, because I have `enums` coming from various places, but all inherit from `String`.

I tried doing this, but got an error:

func something(key: StringLiteralConvertible) {...}
//error: Protocol 'StringLiteralConvertible' can only be used as a generic constraint

Is there a type I can use so I don't have to use `rawValue` every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```
func something<T: RawRepresentable where T.RawValue == String>(key: T) {
    let string = key.rawValue
}

something(Compass.East)
```

This lets you pass in any enum that has `String`s as its values